# No Vboxautostart-service scripts in virtualbox?

Tags: server, virtualbox, autostart

On a 14.04.2 server, I have installed the Ubuntu fork of VirtualBox 4.3.10, with extpack 93012, in the standard manner using:

```
apt-get install virtualbox
```

I've been trying to enable the autostart feature, introduced in version 4.2, on some of my virtual machines, but have discovered that the scripts for the service are not automatically included with the rest of the code, or at least are not installed as standard.

I've found the link to download the [scripts](https://www.virtualbox.org/browser/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Installer/linux/vboxautostart-service.sh) from Oracle, so have got round the problem, but would like to know if these scripts are intentionally missing, or whether there's something awry in my VirtualBox installation? If they're omitted on purpose, what are the likely/possible reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question of whether these scripts were excluded on purpose or not is very vague, and may not have a firm answer in fact.  There's no mention of it anywhere and I believe the VBox packages are community maintained anyway.

I haven't been able to find a true answer, but I know that [there is a bug in Debian on this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=748691) that's been untouched since May 2014 on this issue.  That's where you would track/poke it.

Comment: I was hoping to clarify whether the missing scripts are part of a normal situation for 4.3.10, which appears to be the case. I was asking whether they're omitted on purpose in case there was some sort of vulnerability etc. Thanks for the bug link :)

Comment: @Arronical I don't think that information has any real answers, if they were excluded for such a reason that bug on Debian would've been removed saying "We didn't package it because foobarbaz." and then the bug would be Won'tFix'd.